# How to embed an image in firebase send email

Tags: firebase, email

I'm using firebase extension send email. The goal is to send an email that contains a picture (preferably svg). So far I've gathered the image has to be inside a img tag for max compatibility, but I can't seem to get it right.

Already tried inserting it inline with ${} in js. Also uploaded it to storage and used the signed link. Nothing works. Also tried linking to the local file. Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the solution: use png images.

The usercontent proxy used by gmail doesn't allow svgs. Uploaded the pngs to my own server, embedded the link and its working.

Comment: Can you share the code of embedding image? I am trying it with inages uploaded on firebase storage but it's not showing up, while images from other sources shows up. I also updated rules to make those images public.